# How i prove using reccurence that :$4-u_{n+1}\leq \frac12(4-u_n),n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let us define for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, the sequence $(u_n)$: $u_0=2 , u_{n+1}=5-\frac{4}{u_n}$ such that $2\leq u_n \leq 4$ , I want to prove using recurrence that $4-u_{n+1}\leq \frac12(4-u_n),n\in \mathbb{N}$ ?, The sequence $(u_n)$ is increasing and converge to $4$.

**Attempt**:

The first steps we have $1\leq 1$, my problem in the second step ,now assume $4-u_{n+1}\leq \frac12(4-u_n),n\in \mathbb{N}$ and we shall prove $4-u_{n+2}\leq \frac12(4-u_{n+1}),n\in \mathbb{N}$
I have used the fact that $(u_n)$ is increasing sequence and bounded thus :$u_n\leq u_{n+1}\leq u_{n+2}$ thus $4-u_{n+2}\leq 4-u_{n+1}$ , but i can't continue from this steps ? I want to use the assumption of reccurence correctly

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite the recurrence
$u_{n+1} = 5 - \frac{4}{u_n}$ as
$$4 - u_{n+1} = \frac{4}{u_n} - 1 = \frac{4 - u_n}{u_n}$$
i.e.
$4 - u_{n+1} = \frac{4 - u_n}{u_n}$.
Since the sequence $(u_n)$ is increasing and $u_0 = 2$ we have $u_n \ge 2$, hence $4 - u_{n+1} = \frac{4 - u_n}{u_n} \le \frac{4 - u_n}{2}$

Comment: I want the prove by reccurence  not direct proof

Comment: @zeraouliarafik  What do you mean? I am using the recurrence relation in this proof.

Comment: proof by reccurence (induction)

Comment: @zeraouliarafik But "*recurrence*" $\neq$ "*induction*". The above is a completely legit answer to the question as you originally wrote it. Please do not change the question, especially after answers have been posted.

Comment: @dxiv please look my attemp i mean induction in french called " demonstration par reccurence" just a typo

Comment: @zeraouliarafik I can sympathize, but what got posted was the question in English. If that's not what  you meant to ask, then you should delete it and post a new question. But changing the question after the fact is inconsiderate to those who took the time to answer what was originally asked.

Comment: @dxiv, but in my attempt i showed that i want induction proof

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Posting your attempt was a plus, but what matters in the end is the question being asked, which you [wrote as](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4713428/1) "*I want to prove using recurrence*".

Comment: @dxiv  That is just a typo however my attempt show that i want induction proof and where is the problem if there is someone proof it using induction not direct proof

Comment: *“$u_0 = 2$ and $(u_n)$ is increasing implies $u_n \ge 2$“* is an induction proof.